# Laravel - Api - How to secure using a key

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am creating an API and use a route group for this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/api/v1/', 'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CheckForAuthenticated'] function() {

   Route::group(['prefix'] => '/address'], function() {
       Route::get('/get/', function() {

       }); 

   }); 

});
```

Now what I want to do is to secure the API through a key when I access the url through a GET/POST.

I have created a Middleware but I'm confused how to use the `guard` so let's say I have the following:

```
\Auth::guard('api');

if(\Auth::check()) {
   // This user is signed in 
}
```

However, where do I store/pass the token through the route in order to check to see if the user is authenticated or not?

Comment: Take a look at this https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51

Comment: I might add forcing https and secure cookies

Comment: @Winstar - Thanks for this. But, I'm confused about how to pass the token through the GET request? (i.e. the URL)?

Comment: `https://www.foobar.com/?api_token=yourapitoken` ?